# How to get old state of an array that is inside and object with spread operator in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

i'm tryin to get the old state of my productData[] with spread operator but this array is inside in object.
I have to keep old state because i need to keep my products that are actually in state and to add new products here in Redux.
i try this:

```
case 'ADD_TO_COMPARE':
            return {
                    productData:[...state.productData,action.payload],
                    open:true,                    
            }
```

but didnt work and here is only last product i put here.

Here is my code in reducer on Redux:

```
const initialValue = {

        productData:[],
        open:false
    
}

export const compareReducer = (state = initialValue, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_COMPARE':
            return {
                    productData:[...state.productData,action.payload],
                    open:true,                    
            }
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_COMPARE':
            return initialValue 
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

My Console:
[2 first products are added hard code and the when the  third product is added, always override the last product that is added here in state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC5q1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an obvious issue with the way you're merging the productData. I suspect either `state.productData` is empty on the way in or `action.type` isn't a match.

Syntactically what you're doing works:

```js
// old state
const state = {
  productData: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}],
  otherStuff: 'bananas and wookies'
}

// action
const action = {
  payload: [{id: 3}, {id: 4}]
}

const merged = { // new object literal
  ...state, // keep old state properties
  productData: [ // overwrite the 'productData' from state with
    ...state.productData, // the previous state's product data
    ...action.payload // and the action's payload
  ]};

console.log(merged);
/*
{
  "productData": [
    { "id": 1 }, <-- original state
    { "id": 2 },
    { "id": 3 }, <-- action payload
    { "id": 4 }
  ],
  "otherStuff": "bananas and wookies" <-- original state
}
*/
```

Comment: i add 2 hard products in state and when the third product is added this product always override the last product in state so always i have only three products.                              Can you check my photo added now? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC5q1.png

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your reducer and inspect the incoming state. Is there another reducer interfering? Is there a state/connect problem with the modal? (e.g. Is the app launching the modal with its own detached copy of the state?). I still don't think the reducer is the problem.

Comment: I solve this, i had problem that when i close the modal i dispatch the REMOVE_FROM_COMPARE action and so i have returned the initialState. Thanks